# Netlogo context misaligned

Tags: netlogo

I switched gears from yesterday and now have a workable solution to the pairs problem I posted. However, now I am being defeated by the simplest of issues. I keep getting a mixture of errors. 1)Maketerrain is the first module that runs on setup. It errors saying I can't use maketerrain in an observer context because it patch/turtle only. I've never had a module give such an error, and I use modular code-writing routinely. So this is completely flummoxing me. 2)Wherever I put "tick" (end of go, start of go, middle of go, in some other procedure) further breaks the code, with the same error--"tick is observer and thus will not run because this is X context." I have checked brackets and parentheses more than a dozen times--taking a break and coming back at it fresh to see if I missed something. No errors there that I have been able to find. I am using Netlogo 6.1.1. I am now dizzyingly confused.

Rather than post another lengthy set of code at this juncture, I want to take another few cracks at it myself. So I am asking, can anyone possibly offer a principle or two I can use to try to debug this? Like, what establishes context? What can I do to make the context be what I want and not what gets "implied" by earlier commands? How can I use a module in which patches and turtles do something to set themselves up and still have it run on setup? (Note--moving stuff to the interface did not solve the problem.) What sets the "go" procedure context, what should it be to run, and what can someone do to make it be what it needs to be? What do I do to place tick--a command I have never had problems with before--correctly?

I have scoured stackoverflow, netlogo manual pages and programming guide, books I have, and still cannot debug what seems to be a very very very simple issue.

Comment: The NetLogo site has a resources page with various tutorials. I am a strong believer that tutorials are really important when learning NetLogo because there's a way of thinking that you really need to get and a good tutorial will help to teach you the way of thinking while also teaching you about the language.

Comment: Thanks for the general advice. I fixed the problem by just using my own counter. Tick seems like such a fundamental operation that I would prefer the program trust me to know where I want to specify it.

Comment: You asked for advice to help you solve it yourself so my answer focussed on what to look for. If you post the end of the go procedure and the beginning of the maketerrain procedure, i can probably spot the problem. The fact that you are getting the context error means that the procedure isn't working they way you think it is so your own counter gets rid of the error message but doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the first few lines of the Maketerrain procedure. NetLogo interprets the context from the primitives used. If the first line is something like:

```
set color red
```

then NetLogo 'knows' that this is a procedure to be run by turtles (that is, it is turtle context) because only turtles can `set color` because `color` is a turtle variable. If, however, it starts:

```
ask turtles
[ set color red
```

then it is observer context because the external 'observer' instructs turtles to do things (roughly).

Context is actually an incredibly important concept in NetLogo programming - as you do something like the following, you are constantly changing context:

```
to demo
  ask patches
  [ ask one-of turtles-here 
    [ set color red
    ]
  ]
end
```

It starts in the observer context, then iterates through the patches doing something. In a sense, it is thinking like a patch (and is in patch context). Then you open the next code block with [ and switch to the turtle context so that 'I' (a randomly selected turtle on the current patch) can change colour. Then each ] to end a code block backs out of the layers of context.